# Generating 2 digits that add up to at least 10

Tags: actionscript-3, while-loop

I'm trying to generate two random digits (numbers 0-9) in my Actionscript/Flash game.  However, they must add up to at least 10 (that's part of the game, otherwise the game would be pointless, I can explain why if needed).  Here's my current approach:

```
var first:uint=0;
var second:uint=0;
while(first+second<10)
{
    first=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    second=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}
```

However, I'm worried that the while() loop could go on for a long time (like if the parser generates a 1 every time).  This would be unlikely, but possible.  Is there any better approach for this?

Comment: Generate `first` and then `second = 10 - first + random(10-first)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your first and second number go from 0 to 9, while the minimum need to get out of the loop is 10.

What you can do instead is generate your first number, find the minimum needed to get past your requirement of 10 as the second number. Then add another random number on top. This way, even if the second added random number is 0, it'll be guaranteed to add up to 10.

Also, for the first number, you'd need to make sure it is at least 1 or larger, as if any of the two were 0, the other would have to be 10 to add up to 10, which would break your requirement of having a number from 0 to 9.

And the randomness range of the second number would also need to take in consideration how big it can be to not go over 9.

Just off the top of my head (didn't test this explicitly):

```
// first number goes from 1 to 9
var first:int = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
var second:int = 10 - first;

// On the second number, add a random value on top, taking care not to go over 9
second += Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - second));
```

Comment: looks like Jongware beat me to it in his comment >.>

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm sure generating a random number every time would work in 99% of cases, but this will work 100% of the time.

Thanks for the comments too instead of just throwing the code at me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to do this thousands of times a second, this is fine. Off the top of my head, I couldn't think of another way to do it without harming the integrity of the (pseudo)randomness.

Edit: I stand corrected, I think Jongware's answer is the one you're looking for.